# Duda ajax en data

Tags: ajax

En este codigo para enviar datos por ajax ¿como se interpreta la parte de data?El id parece que no lo asigna con los dos puntos(:) ¿por que?. Ademas ¿de donde saca el id (si lo necesitan paso el codigo completo). Estoy liado en esta parte (mas abajo pongo la manera que yo suelo entenderlo):

```
function eliminar (id){
    var q= $("#q").val();
    var id_categoria= $("#id_categoria").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./ajax/buscar_productos.php",
        data: "id="+id,"q":q+"id_categoria="+id_categoria,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados").html(datos);
        load(1);
        }
    });
}
```

Yo hasta ahora entendia bien como pasar el data asi:

```
    function ejecutarAjax(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    //alert("hola");
  var datosEnviados =
  {
    'usuario' : $('#txtUsuario').val(),
    'contra'  : $('#txtPassword').val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    type      : 'POST',
    url       : 'registrar_usuario.php',
    data      : datosEnviados,
    dataType  : 'json',
    encode    : true,
```

Pero esta manera de pasar los datos me desconcierta ¿podria alguien ayudarme a entenderlo?

Comment: Es que esto parece ser erróneo: `data: "id="+id,"q":q+"id_categoria="+id_categoria`  sería algo parecido a lo  de abajo, incluso puedes omitir las comillas en el valor de la izquierda: `var data={ id: id, q:q, id_categoria:d_categoria }`  Se supone que los valores de la derecha son variables que ya existen.

Comment: la sintaxis del paso de datos a traves de la propiedad data esta mal , la sintaxis es esta data: {status: status, name: name},

Comment: El id se lo pasas como parámetro en la función eliminar, de ahi lo saca

Comment: Lo lógico sería usar la sintaxis que mencionaís pero el código es correcto y funciona. De hecho corrigiéndolo como mencionaís deja de funcionar. Así que supongo que se debe poder mandar así. Lo que no entiendo es como lo hace. ¿Alguna otra idea de como funciona esto?

Comment: Dices que funciona, pero mira bien la request: seguramente no esté mandando el id

Comment: Tal como dice @PabloLozano es un parámetro diferente, q creo que puede ser un parámetro que hace referencia al envío de los datos en forma de querystring ("id="+id correspondería a esta forma) y que se puede usar como control, te paso un ejemplo de ajaxadapter en el que dentro de otro entorno se usa q por si sirve de ayuda, yo nunca he usado el parámetro. https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3548

Answer (score 1):

Este es un ejemplo de la [documentación de jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Observa la creación de la variable `data`:

```
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

Como puedes observar, el valor de la izquierda en cada par clave/valor separado por los dos puntos puede escribirse sin comillas y será la clave que buscarás en el servidor con `$_POST` o con `$_GET` según el caso.

En cuanto al valor de la derecha, puede ser tanto un valor que recuperas ahí mismo, que escribes a mano, o que recoges de una variable.

En tu caso, puedes hacerlo así:

```
    data: {id:id, q:q, id_categoria:id_categoria}
```

En cuanto a la duda que tienes sobre `id`,  es el parámetro que recibe la función eliminar, por lo tanto lo puedes usar, porque está dentro del ámbito de la función.

Comment: Entiendo la documentacion que proporcionas. Lo que no entendía es lo que envíe yo y que, repito, funciona perfectamente. Tal vez sea una manera antigua de escribirlo por que veo que no usa los corchetes sino la concatenación. ¿Te suena que se pueda hacer así también)
De igual manera, veo que cuando uso el código que proporcionas también funciona.

Comment: @RicardoKra ¿dices que así funciona? `data: "id="+id,"q":q+"id_categoria="+id_categoria` puede ser que se enviaría quizá algo como `id: 1, q: Pedro5=5` ... suponiendo que `id` vale `1` y que `q` vale `Pedro` y que `id_categoria` vale `5`... Prueba a hacer un `var_dump($_POST);` cuando envías los datos como los tienes en tu pregunta y dime lo que muestra en pantalla.

Comment: Si, lo que mencionas (data: "id="+id,"q":q+"id_categoria="+id_categoria) si funciona correctamente. Por eso preguntaba si te sonaba que se pueda hacer así también.
¿Donde debo hacer el var_dump($_POST)? Ademas fíjate que se envía por get. Yo hice el var_dump que indicas a continuación de la llamada a la función eliminar y no muestra nada.

Comment: @RicardoKra en el archivo `registrar_usuario.php` puedes hacer un `var_dump($_GET);` o bien un `var_dump($_POST);`. Eso te mostrará en qué forma se están enviando los datos.

Comment: Así esta el código:
<script>
function eliminar (id){
  var q= $("#q").val();
  var id_categoria= $("#id_categoria").val();
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
   url: "./ajax/buscar_productos.php",
   data: "id="+id,"q":q+"id_categoria="+id_categoria, 
   beforeSend: function(objeto){
    $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
     },
   success: function(datos){
   $("#resultados").html(datos);
   load(1);
   }
  });
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
  <?php
   if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
  ?>
   eliminar(<?php echo intval($_GET['delete'])?>);  
  <?php
   }
  ?>
 });

Comment: @RicardoKra ¿Eso muestra el `var_dump`?   No puede ser... Perdón, **donde debes hacer el `var_dump` es en `buscar_productos.php`** que es el destinatario de la petición. Me confundí con tu segundo código.

Comment: @RicardoKra me refiero a hacer el `var_dump` en este archivo: `buscar_productos.php` que es el que va a recibir los datos. Eso permitirá ver cómo están viajando al servidor.

Comment: He puesto el var_dump($_POST) en la primera linea de buscar_productos.php y no muestra nada en consola. ¿No sera por que se envía por Get?

Comment: Aunque se enviase por `GET` debería mostrar algo, pero puedes poner también `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: Perdón, fuí impreciso antes. Al hacer el var_dump (tanto con post como con get) me sale esto. Lo estoy haciendo de nuevo en la primera linea de buscar_productos.php
Uncaught ReferenceError: var_dump is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (stock.php?delete=8:256)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)

Comment: Supongo que tiene mas complejidad de la que puedo explicar. Si quieres ver el proyecto completo esta en:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/sistema-de-inventario-php/files/latest/download

Comment: Entiendo que no se podrá mostrar el var_dump así por así. Sin embargo puedes probar a mostrarlo en el `success` de Ajax: `console.log(datos);` y en vez de var_dump puedes usar `print_r($_GET);` Debes revisar la consola para ver el resultado.

Comment: No muestra nada usando el console.log y print_r. Bueno, si muestra algo pero no es lo que esperamos:
 <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <strong>Aviso!</strong> Datos eliminados exitosamente.
   </div>

Comment: @RicardoKra para hacer la prueba debes comentar todo lo que sea salida por patalla dejando solo el `print_r`.

Comment: Eso que puse es lo que sale en console (en chrome). No es lo que esperabas supongo.

Answer (score 1):

Extraigamos el objeto de configuración y veamos lo que realmente pasa:

```js
const id=0;
const q= 'Q';
const id_categoria='CAT'

let datos = {
  type: "GET",
  url: "./ajax/buscar_productos.php",
  data: "id="+id,"q":q+"id_categoria="+id_categoria,
  beforeSend: 'beforeSend',
  success: 'success'
}

console.log(datos);
```

Como se puede ver, ese código se podría formatear/identar como:

```js
function eliminar (id){
    var q= $("#q").val();
    var id_categoria= $("#id_categoria").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./ajax/buscar_productos.php",
        data: "id="+id,
        "q":q+"id_categoria="+id_categoria, //las comillas son optativas
        beforeSend: function(objeto){
          $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
        },
        success: function(datos){
          $("#resultados").html(datos);
          load(1);
        }
    });
}
```

Es decir, que realmente `"q"` es un atributo del objeto de configuración de la llamada AJAX que seguramente está siendo ignorado por jquery .